# PHP - Error parsing a string with code

Tags: php, string, parsing, version

I'm having a problem with some code that used to work in PHP 4.X and is not working in PHP 5.2.4

First of all, there is a small example of a code similar to the one is causing the problem. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with a small example.

```
<?php
class Example{

  public function showExample()
  {
    $ind = 1;
    $m   = "method";
    $str2 = "{call method}";

    $str2 = str_replace("{call $m}" , "<?php  print( \$pre$ind ); ?>", $str2);

    echo $str2 . "\n";
   }
}

$e = new Example();
$e -> showExample();
?>
```

What this code is doing is building a string with some php code to execute later on. In particular, the code generated will print the value of a variable named "$pre" + a variable number. In this case, the output is the following:

```
 <?php  print( $pre1 ); ?>
```

Everything runs fine with this code. The problem is when I use it in the context of a much bigger class, that is part of a framework I've been using for a long time. I cannot paste here the whole source of the class, but the problematic lines are the following (I simplified them a little bit to remove the str_replace, but the error still appears):

```
        $myVar = "value";
        $myVar2 = 2;
        $str2 = "<?php print( \$myVar$myVar2 );  ?>";
```

When I load the file, I get the following two messages:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /Users/giove/Sites/mundial/htmltemplate.php on line 252
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Users/giove/Sites/mundial/htmltemplate.php on line 252
```

I can fix the warning by removing the '\', but that changes the semantics of the code, so it's not a real possibility.

Now, the weirdest part is I can remove both errors by breaking or removing the sequence "

This seems to be a difference in versions, but I haven't been able to find any mention to it on the change logs.

---

Now I've got a working solution from Cryo: split the string

```
 "<?php"
```

to prevent its 'evalution' (I'm not sure if that's really an evaluation).

Nevertheless, I still would like to know the reason for this weird behavior.

Cryo: thanks for your help, I'll mark the question as answered in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that PHP is catching on the re-opening of the php tag `<?php`, try splitting just that:

```
$str2 = "<?" . "php print( \$myVar$myVar2 );  ?>";
```

Or use single quotes and concatenation:

```
$str2 = '<?php print( $myVar' . $myVar2 . ' );  ?>';
```

Comment: Great idea! It is now working properly, although it still not answers the question "why"? ;)
BTW, I also tried with the second alternative and it didn't work but the error message changed:

     PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /Users/giove/Sites/mundial/htmltemplate.php on line 252


I'll check if this solution works in all the other similar cases I have.
Thanks!

Comment: @nozebacle I can find no reference to the way <?php is handled being changed between PHP4 and PHP5.  What exactly is it that you're doing with the generated PHP code?  Writing it to a file and then including it?  I've run both of my lines as well as your exact original and they all echo the correct information for me even your original after being output to a file and then included (prints '2').  Either I'm not testing in the way that you're executing or it's a configuration issue.

Comment: It's very strange indeed. The issue does not seem to be related with what I'm doing with the generated code, but it seems to be an issue with the way it is written, i.e. it's a parsing/syntactical error and not an interpretation/semantical error. As I told before, the weirdest thing is that the same code is ok in one file, but produces the error in another. I'll keep on looking at the issue and I'll try to find info about the parsing process.

Answer (score 1):

Cryo is on the right track, though I think the actual issue is that PHP evaluates variables within double-quoted strings. However, the slash should prevent the variable from being evaluated. So:

```
$a = "somestring"
$b = "\$a" // -> \$a
$c = '\$a' // -> \$a
```

I think your string is getting evaluated in an odd way such that the \ + $myVar is evaluated in a strange way.